# Running a Visual Basic Program on an Android Phone

Tags: basic

I wrote this Visual Basic program back in 1999.
It runs on a Windows Pocket PC.
I would like to use it with a droid phone.

Any guesses about how to get to Point B (droid phone) from Point A (PPC)?

I just finished my first java program to run on windows tablets and desktops.

If that helps me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

you can't run .exe files in android phones, but you can run .exe files on pocket pc

to run your program on android phone you will write the code in eclipse in export it as apk file

Comment: In other words I have to rewrite it in java?  Are there any short cuts?  Like importing the VB code into something that will translate it to code that runs on android?

Comment: Yes you have rewrite it in java to run on android phones and tablets

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes close to this I can think of is [Jabaco](http://www.jabaco.org). Its a VB6 clone written entirely in Java and outputs a Java applet as the result. I have only brief experience with it so I cannot say for certain that it would take direct VB code. Just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Thanks.  When I get my job jar down to the half way point I hope to try this.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind losing the Android OS system, you probably are able to install Linux on the phone. Then install wine, and you could possibly run your .exe file.